# Fill PDF form using perl

Tags: perl, pdf, pdf-form

I need to fill PDF form with a data in perl. I use module **CAM::PDF**

Code is pretty simple:

```
my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($infile) || die "$CAM::PDF::errstr\n";

my @list;
push @list, 'IBAN1';          push @list, '11';
push @list, 'IBAN2';          push @list, 'WWWW';
push @list, 'IBAN3';          push @list, '2222';
push @list, 'IBAN4';          push @list, '2222';
push @list, 'IBAN5';          push @list, '22';
push @list, 'Telefon';        push @list, '1234567890';

$doc->fillFormFields({}, @list);
$doc->cleanoutput($outfile);
```

It works, it fill fields properly, but it does not look properly. See picture.

In a form there are special squares for every character. When you edit PDF manually, cursor automatically jumps to the next square.  But when I fill this pdf form with a script, it just place text as it is ignoring this squares.

Note that there is no separate ID for every square. All 10 squares for Telefoon is like one field and has one ID 'Telefoon'

Any idea how to fill PDF form properly (so it looks nice) in perl? Or some other ways of doing this?

[image: PDF Form]

And here are fields with their IDs:

[image: IDs]

Thanks for help in advance.

Pavel

Comment: Is the Comb property set in the IBAN and Telefoon fields? If so, then you have to force the recreation of the appearances when filling the form.

Comment: What does 'Comb property' mean? And how I can force the recreation?

Comment: @MaxWyss highlight, the comment above was directed at you.